# How do I append data retrieved via Ajax correctly to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I insert several(`array`) value with `json_encode` in one row from database table, now want echo they as order with jquery.

This is output from my PHP code with `json_encode`:

```
[{
    "guide": null,
    "residence": [{
        "name_r": "jack"
    }, {
        "name_r": "jim"
    }, {
        "name_r": "sara"
    }],
    "residence_u": [{
        "units": ["hello", "how", "what"],
        "extra": ["11", "22", "33"],
        "price": ["1,111,111", "2,222,222", "3,333,333"]
    }, {
        "units": ["fine"],
        "extra": ["44"],
        "price": ["4,444,444"]
    }, {
        "units": ["thanks", "good"],
        "extra": ["55", "66"],
        "price": ["5,555,555", "6,666,666"]
    }]
}]
```

And is my js code in ajax call (`$.ajax({...`):

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data[0].residence, function (index, value) {
        $('ol#residence_name').append('<li><a href="" class="tool_tip" title="ok">' + value.name_r + '</a><div class="tooltip"></div></li>');
        var info = data[0].residence_u[index];
        $.each(info.units, function (index, value) {
            $('ol#residence_name li .tooltip').append(value + ' & ' + info.extra[index] + ' & ' + info.price[index] + '<br>');
        })
    });
```

**Now by above js code, i have in output this:**

> `jack`
>  `hello` & `11` & `1,111,111`
>  `how` & `22` &
>   `2,222,222`
>  `what` & `33` & `3,333,333,`
>  `fine` & `44` & `4,444,444`
>   `thanks` & `55` & `5,555,555`
>  `good` & `66` & `6,666,666`

> `jim`
>  `fine` & `44` & `4,444,444`
>  `thanks` & `55` & `5,555,555`
>  `good` & `66` & `6,666,666`

> `sara`
>  `thanks` & `55` & `5,555,555`
>  `good` & `66` & `6,666,666`

**I want as:**

> `jack`
>  `hello` & `11` & `1,111,111`
>  `how` & `22` &
>   `2,222,222`
>  `what` & `33` & `3,333,333,`

> `jim`
>  `fine` & `44` & `4,444,444`

> `sara`
>  `thanks` & `55` & `5,555,555`
>  `good` & `66` & `6,666,666`

What do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a reference to the tooltip element and append the info to it:

```
var $li = $('<li><a href="" class="tool_tip" title="ok">' + value.name_r + '</a></li>');
var $tooltip = $('<div class="tooltip"></div>').appendTo($li);

var info = data[0].residence_u[index];

$.each(info.units, function (index, value) {
    $tooltip.append(value + ' & ' + info.extra[index] + ' & ' + info.price[index] + '<br>');
});

$li.appendTo('#residence_name');
```

---

**Why does your code produce this result?**

Because `$('ol#residence_name li .tooltip')` will select *every* `.tooltip` element in *every* `li` inside `#residence_name`, not just the currently created one.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a complicated data structure you're starting with - my first instinct would be to reorganise it into a less brain-melting format!  But assuming the structure is fixed, a nice clear iteration structure can help to de-confuse matters.  I've provided some code below which doesn't do anything, but which does provide an easier-to-understand framework in which to work.  At every stage the variables you need are extracted ready for use, and it's up to you what to do with the data.  Untested, but should work :)

```
// Declare the variables we're going to use
var i, j; // Iterating variables
var name, unitsArray, extraArray, priceArray; // Outer loop
var unit, extra, price; // Inner loop

// Loop through the people
for( i in data[0].residence ) {

  // Assign the outer-loop variables
  name = data[0].residence[i].name_r;
  unitsArray = data[0].residence_u[i].units;
  extraArray = data[0].residence_u[i].extra;
  priceArray = data[0].residence_u[i].price;

  // Do something here with the name

  // For each person, loop through the things they said
  for( j in unitsArray ) {

    // Assign the inner-loop variables
    unit  = unitsArray[j];
    extra = extraArray[j];
    price = priceArray[j];

    // Do something here with the 3 inner-loop variables

  }

}
```